# Python login script using dictionary

Tags: python, authentication

I am making a login script for python and it will create passwords and write them to a text file like (username:password). But I want to add a login script that will check to see if the username and password is in the text file.

```
def reg():
    print('Creating new text file') 
    name = input('Username: ')
    passwrd = input('Password: ')
    with open("users.txt", "r+") as f:
     old = f.read()
     f.seek(0)
     f.write(name + ":" + passwrd + "\n" + old)
    f.close()
def login():
    user = input("username: ")
    passwrd = input("password: ")

    with open('users.txt') as f:
       credentials = [x.strip().split(':') for x in f.readlines()]

    for user,passwrd in credentials:
    (This is where i want to add the code)

reg()
login()
```

I think it would be something like.

```
for user,passwrd in credentials:
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

Comment: That's nice.  Oh did you have a question?

Comment: yes i want to add a piece of code that checks to see if the variables user and passwrd are in the file and if they are print "correct" or "incorrect"

Comment: change `for user,passwrd` to `if [user,passwrd]` if you want to check whether the inputs are in credentials list

Comment: Yes it's working now thank you verry helpfull

Answer (score 1):

If you make credentials a dict, then you can do:

```
if user in credentials and credentials[user] == password:
   //success
else:
   //failure
```

This should work for making credentials be a dict

```
with open('users.txt') as f:
   credentials = dict([x.strip().split(':') for x in f.readlines()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You just check to see if they match.  Note that you need to make the variable names different:

```
for user2,passwrd2 in credentials:
    if (user == user2 and passwrd == passwrd2):
       print ("Passed")
```

Comment: you might want to `break`/`return` if there is a match, since I doubt there will another line with the same combination